# jboss is not making hibernate/JNDI connections

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jboss, struts2

I am using JBoss 4.2 GA and deploy my application there using JNDI naming for my data source.

I tested it on the local server and it works fine but when I put it on the remote server it can't make the database connection and also there is no log in JBoss.

I am using an oracle database.

On the remote server the "abc-ds.xml" has the appropriate connection details.

Please help I have to make it ready till evening.

Comment: show your database configuration

Comment: Maybe the DB is not accepting connections which do not come from localhost...

Comment: <local-tx-datasource>
 
 <jndi-name>sampleDS</jndi-name>
  <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.1.40:1521:orcl</connection-url>
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>   
    <user-name>user</user-name>
    <password>pass</password>
</local-tx-datasource>

Comment: Can JBoss 4 datasources even be accessed remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the remote server can see the db server. Sometimes you have to use fully qualified name of db host. Try with db IP address in xml file possibly. See if you can ping the db server from jboss machine.

Comment: i am using <local-tx-datasource>
 
 <jndi-name>sampleDS</jndi-name>
  <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.1.40:1521:orcl</connection-url>
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>   
    <user-name>user</user-name>
    <password>pass</password>
</local-tx-datasource>

Answer (score 0):

It may be you cannot create datasource in your remote server.